# Get values from XML column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an XML column with this value

```
<sso_links>
   <linktype>mytype</linktype>
   <url>http://mydomain.com</url>
   <linktype>mytype2</linktype>
   <url>http://somedomain.com</url>
</sso_links>
```

I've tried using SQL to query this by value but this only returns scalar type

```
SELECT XMLCOLUMN.value('//linktype[1]', varchar(max)),
XMLCOLUMN.value('//url[1]', varchar(max))
from table
where someid = '1'
```

This produced 2 rows from the XML. How can I output all values?

Answer (score 1):

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE docs (pk INT PRIMARY KEY, xCol XML not null)
```

Insert the values

```
INSERT INTO docs VALUES (1, '<sso_links>
<linktype>mytype</linktype>
<url>http://mydomain.com</url>
<linktype>mytype2</linktype>
<url>http://somedomain.com</url>
</sso_links>')
```

Now select the values you want

```
SELECT xCol.value('(/sso_links//linktype/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS linktype
      ,xCol.value('(/sso_links//url/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS url
      ,xCol.value('(/sso_links//linktype/node())[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS linktype2
      ,xCol.value('(/sso_links//url/node())[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS url2
  FROM docs 
 WHERE pk = 1
```

Give it a try!

Comment: THis works - but **only** if you have exactly two `<linktype>` and two `<url>` subnodes....

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "generic" version that will parse all subnodes under `<sso_links>` and produce their name and value, use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    NodeName = node.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),
    NodeValue = node.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlColumn.nodes('/sso_links/*') AS links(node)
WHERE 
    SomeID = 1
```

For your sample XML, I get an output of:

```
NodeName    NodeValue
linktype    mytype
url         http://mydomain.com
linktype    mytype2
url         http://somedomain.com
```

Since it uses no specific node names or indexes, this will work for any number of subnodes under `<sso_links>`